# Replace method in pandas not giving expected result

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have data as below:

```
123.12.23.2
110.22.21.23
```

I want to mask this data as below one

```
1xx.xx.xx.x
```

So I tried below code :

```
 readFile = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/siddhesh.kalgaonkar/Desktop/data01.txt",header=None)
 readFile.columns = ['IP']
 readFile['IP']=readFile['IP'].str.replace("(?<! )","X").astype('str')
 readFile
```

but I gives me data as below one which is not correct:

```
                                                  IP
0  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
2  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
```

I am new to pandas. So where am I going wrong ?

Also, I want to do it without pandas because the platform on which I would be deploying this code may be won't have pandas. So need to be ready for the other scenario as well. Below is my code:

```
readFiles=open("C:/Users/siddhesh.kalgaonkar/Desktop/data01.txt","r")
 finalValues = re.sub("(?<! ).","X",readFiles)
```

It gives below error:

```
>>> finalValues = re.sub("(?<! ).","X",readFiles)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I want to split this data on the basis of delimiter (in case I have multiple columns) and then I have to apply regex logic. Please help me out here.

Comment: What is not correct with the readFile dataframe generated from the pd.read_csv call?  Whats wrong about it?

Comment: I have modified my question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: So your problem is the code replacing the '.' into X?

Comment: Everything into X except first digit and '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you decide to use pandas:

```
readFile = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/siddhesh.kalgaonkar/Desktop/data01.txt",header=None)
readFile.columns = ['IP']
readFile['IP'] = readFile['IP'].replace(regex='((?<=[0-9])[0-9]|(?<=\.)[0-9])',value='X')
print(readFile)
```

and this without pandas:

```
readFile = open("C:/Users/siddhesh.kalgaonkar/Desktop/data01.txt","r")
for line in readFile:
    lines = line.strip()
    finalline = re.sub(pattern='((?<=[0-9])[0-9]|(?<=\.)[0-9])',repl='X',string=lines)
    print(finalline)
```

`(?<=[0-9])[0-9]` this part matches if the current position in the string is a digit and is preceded by a digit.

`|` or

`(?<=\.)[0-9])` this part matches if the current position in the string is is a digit and is preceded by a period.

Comment: But what if I have multiple columns and I want to use delimiter to separate columns and then apply the logic. Can you modify your answer using without pandas.Using pandas I know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

This is pure(almost) python:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] + '.'.join(['X' * len(c) for c in x[1:].split('.')]), my_df['IP']))
```

Explanation:
 - Use the map to iterate over each row in my_df['IP'] column.
 - Per each IP value, split into first char and others using the `x[0], x[1:]`
 notation.
 - Get each part in `x[1:]` using the split method.
 - For each part get its length and accordingly create a string made of X's.
 - Rejoin this X's string into one string with '.' between them.

If using python2 you dont need the `list`.

Comment: Yeah, it worked can you just explain join method in detail. Also, why do we need list over here